# HttpClient causes 'System.Net.Http' assembly not found exception even though .NET v.4.0 is installed

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, console-application

I'm not sure why am I getting this exception. I included `System.Net.Http` assembly into my `C#` console project. It is compiled with VS 2010 using `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile`.

So when I try to use [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class in my code, the app works fine on my Windows 8.1 development machine, but when I run the `Release` build of the executable on a Windows 7 machine with .NET Framework 4 installed, I get the following exception:

[image]

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly `System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a` or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

What am I missing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to be an issue with the The Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile **redistributable package**, please try reinstalling it or updating [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24872)

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it. It offered an option to repair it. So I did, rebooted that Win7 machine, tried my app and got the same error. So there must be something else to it?

Comment: Then probably there is an issue with the release, try to clean, build and release again. In the release verify the System.Net.Http.dll exists

Comment: Oh, shoot. You got it. for some reason VS didn't set `Copy Local` to `true` for the `System.Net.Http` assembly properties. So it didn't copy that DLL. OK. Now when I have that DLL copy on a Win7 machine it works. Thanks for your help!